# schedule a method at random time interval in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, schedule

I want to call a method for moving an object on screen at a random time interval.

I tried making this:

on init method

```
[self scheduleOnce:@selector(addMonster:) delay:1.0];
```

and inside method 'addMonster' I do again :

```
randomFrequenza = ((float)arc4random() / 0x100000000) * 1.6 + 0.2;

[self scheduleOnce: @selector(addMonster:) delay: randomFrequenza];
```

it works exactly but on console I get a lot of errors :

```
-[CCNode schedule:interval:repeat:delay:] : Selector 'addMonster:' was already scheduled on <GameScene = 0x17ef17f0 | Name = (null)>
```

Comment: ignore the warnings, or remove them from CCScheduler - this shouldn't be logged, it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Create a flag and modify it on "AddMonster" method (BOOL variable).

Then, instead of

```
[self scheduleOnce: @selector(addMonster:) delay: randomFrequenza];
```

Use:

```
if(!flag){
   [self scheduleOnce: @selector(addMonster:) delay: randomFrequenza];
}
```